# Is it possible to dynamically draw a bezier curve around an object without stopping -2d/3d mouse

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I attempted to draw "vines" on top of my object in a spiral fashion via the bezier curve using the draw tool. I was striving to get one continous curve as I dynamically rotate my model . However, I could only do it in segments.  I used both the 2d and 3d mouse.

For the attached pic I have nevertheless converted this curve to a mesh and remeshed it so as to avoid non-manifold geometry and it is now in 3d printable format. Unfortunately the segmented vines just dont look good.
It would just be great if I could get a continuous curve. Perhaps some-one has some tips?

[image]

[image]

Comment: to continue extruding a curve, move the cursor to the next point where you want a control point and use CTRL-right click.  Would that work?

Comment: @Marty Fouts: Im afraid that does not work. The curve just follows some random trajectory instead of my designated points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you maybe can try is this:

Model a new curve like your branch, add a archimedian spiral (is in a curves add-on), give...

[image]

...this some turns and height and then ....

[image]

...give your "branch" curve a curve modifier ...

[image]

...and you can get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I managed to create something like you have but I have no way of projecting it onto the topology of my target mesh with the draw tool in edit mode. Unless there is a tool for this projection outside of the draw tool?